# Unity Visual Scripting: Trigger Custom Event from C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying out the Unity Visual Scripting system.  What I'd like to do is have a custom event I can trigger in C# and have it run the visual script to do some work, but I can't seem to get a simple print test to work.

I have the following:

[image]

I then have the following supporting code:

```
[Button]
void DebugTest()
{
    var method = "DebugTest";
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"Triggerating! {method}");
    CustomEvent.Trigger(
        this.gameObject,
        method
      );
}
```

In the console window it outputs:

> Triggerating! DebugTest

But not the print from the actual visual scripting editor.  I've tried running this as an editor button click as well as from the 'Start()' function when entering play mode but to no avail.

I'm using Unity 2012.2.18f1 with Visual Scripting 1.7.7 if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

As seems to always be the case, after I write it up I find the solution.

It appears the above works, so long as it's being executed against an object *in the scene*.  If the object is a prefab it won't run at all and will silently fail.

It also appears it won't work unless the game is running, it can't run in editor mode in my trials, which is a shame.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but fixing those two issues solved the problem for me.

Comment: Code attached to prefabs only runs once instantiated

Comment: Maybe I should clarify: i was running it by virtue of having a button in the editor that executed code referenced in a prefab.  The C# code definitely ran despite it being a non instantiated prefab but the visual editor code did not.

Comment: You are correct, however I've also noticed some weird as hell behaviour recently where the event simply doesn't reach the object.